# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'transactions' into field. Choices are: amount, created_at, id, received_transfers, sent_

Tags: python, django

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    CHARGE = 1
    PURCHASE = 2
    TRANSFER_RECEIVED = 3
    TRANSFER_SENT = 4

    TRANSACTION_TYPES_CHOICES = (
        (CHARGE, 'Charge'),
        (PURCHASE, 'Purchase'),
        (TRANSFER_SENT, 'Transfer sent'),
        (TRANSFER_RECEIVED, 'Transfer received'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='transactions', on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    transaction_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=TRANSACTION_TYPES_CHOICES, default=CHARGE)
    amount = models.BigIntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user}: {self.get_transaction_type_display()} -> {self.amount} Rial'

    @classmethod
    def get_report(cls):
        positive_transactions = Sum('transactions__amount',
                                    filter=Q(transactions__transaction_type__in=[cls.CHARGE, cls.TRANSFER_RECEIVED]))
        negative_transactions = Sum('transactions__amount',
                                    filter=Q(transactions__transaction_type__in=[cls.PURCHASE, cls.TRANSFER_SENT]))

        users = User.objects.all().annotate(
            transactions_count=Count('transactions__id'),
            balance=Coalesce(positive_transactions, 0) - Coalesce(negative_transactions, 0)
        )
        return users

    @classmethod
    def get_total_balance(cls, user):
        query_set = cls.get_report()
        return query_set.aggregate(Sum('balance'))

    @classmethod
    def user_balance(cls, user):
        positive_transactions = Sum('amount', filter=Q(
            transactions__transaction_type__in=[cls.CHARGE, cls.TRANSFER_RECEIVED]))
        negative_transactions = Sum('amount', filter=Q(
            transactions__transaction_type__in=[cls.PURCHASE, cls.TRANSFER_SENT]))

        user_balance = user.transactions.all().aggregate(
            balance=Coalesce(positive_transactions, 0) - Coalesce(negative_transactions, 0))
        return user_balance.get('balance', 0)


class UserBalance(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='balance_records', on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    balance = models.BigIntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user}: {self.balance} - {self.created_at}'

    @classmethod
    def record_user_balance(cls, user):
        user_balance = Transaction.user_balance(user)

        instance = cls.objects.create(user=user, balance=user_balance)
        return instance

    @classmethod
    def record_all_users_balance(cls):
        for user in User.objects.all():
            cls.record_user_balance(user)
```

when i run `UserBalance.record_all_users_balance()` in console i get this error:

```
>>>UserBalance.record_all_users_balance()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 364, in runcode
    coro = func()
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "*\Python\PythonWebProjects\djangoProject01\transaction\models.py", line 76, in record_all_users_balance
    cls.record_user_balance(user)
  File "*\Python\PythonWebProjects\djangoProject01\transaction\models.py", line 68, in record_user_balance
    user_balance = Transaction.user_balance(user)
  File "*\Python\PythonWebProjects\djangoProject01\transaction\models.py", line 53, in user_balance
    user_balance = user.transactions.all().aggregate(
  File "*\Python\PythonWebProjects\djangoProject01\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 592, in aggregate
    return self.query.chain().get_aggregation(self.db, kwargs)
  File "*\Python\PythonWebProjects\djangoProject01\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 398, in get_aggregation
    aggregate = aggregate_expr.resolve_expression(
  File "*\Python\PythonWebProjects\djangoProject01\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\expressions.py", line 701, in resolve_expression
    lhs = self.lhs.resolve_expression(
  File "*\Python\PythonWebProjects\djangoProject01\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\expressions.py", line 950, in resolve_expression
    c.source_expressions[pos] = arg.resolve_expression(
  File "*\Python\PythonWebProjects\djangoProject01\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\aggregates.py", line 65, in resolve_expression
    c.filter = c.filter and c.filter.resolve_expression(
  File "*\Python\PythonWebProjects\djangoProject01\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query_utils.py", line 87, in resolve_expression
    clause, joins = query._add_q(
  File "*\Python\PythonWebProjects\djangoProject01\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1577, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "*\Python\PythonWebProjects\djangoProject01\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1427, in build_filter
    lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg, summarize)
  File "*\Python\PythonWebProjects\djangoProject01\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1237, in solve_lookup_type
    _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
  File "*\Python\PythonWebProjects\djangoProject01\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1725, in names_to_path
    raise FieldError(
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'transactions' into field. Choices are: amount, created_at, id, received_transfers, sent_transfers, transaction_type, user, user_id
```

Comment: Remove transactions__ from this statement transactions__transaction_type__in